# How to return a table of records from a PLSQL function?

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql

I have a function which is having three different queries. First query is returning a single record in a plsql record type.Second query is returning another  single value and third is also returning a different single value. Now I want to append first record with those two values and return a table of that new record from my function. How can I achieve that.

```
create or replace function test(p_actBillDat date) return <what should I    return> as
 type tab_accountNum is table of account.account_num%type;
 var_accountNum tab_accountNum;

 type query1Record is record(
 accountNum account.account_num%type,
 customerRef customer.customer_ref%type,
 internalCreditScore CUSTOMERATTRIBUTES.Internal_Credit_Score%type);

 var_query1Rec query1Record;

 var_nsfDat date;
 var_writeOffdat date;



 cursor cur_accountNum is
 select ACCOUNT_NUM
  from BILLSUMMARY
 where trunc(ACTUAL_BILL_DTM) = p_actBillDat
   and CANCELLATION_REQUEST_DAT is null;
begin
  open cur_accountNum;
  Loop
    fetch cur_accountNum bulk collect
  into var_accountNum limit 100;
close cur_accountNum;
for i in 1 .. var_accountNum.count
loop 
  select A.ACCOUNT_NUM, A.CUSTOMER_REF, CA.INTERNAL_CREDIT_SCORE 
    into var_query1Rec
    from ACCOUNT A, CUSTOMERATTRIBUTES CA, CONTACTDETAILS CD, CONTACT CNT  
            where A.ACCOUNT_NUM = var_accountNum(i) and  
            A.CUSTOMER_REF = CA.CUSTOMER_REF(+) and  
            A.CUSTOMER_REF = CD.CUSTOMER_REF and  
            CNT.CUSTOMER_REF = A.CUSTOMER_REF and  
            CD.CONTACT_SEQ = CNT.CONTACT_SEQ and  
            CD.CONTACT_SEQ = 1 and  
            CD.START_DAT = (select min(CNTD.START_DAT)  
                            from CONTACTDETAILS CNTD  
                            where CNTD.CONTACT_SEQ = CD.CONTACT_SEQ and  
                            CNTD.CUSTOMER_REF = A.CUSTOMER_REF);

  select max(AP.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT_DAT) into var_writeOffdat 
            from ACCOUNT A, ACCOUNTPAYMENT AP  
            where A.ACCOUNT_NUM = AP.ACCOUNT_NUM and  
            A.ACCOUNT_NUM = var_accountNum(i) AND  
            A.TOTAL_WRITEOFF_TOT <> 0 and  
            (AP.PAYMENT_ORIGIN_ID = 2 or  AP.PAYMENT_ORIGIN_ID = 3) and  
            AP.CANCELLED_DTM is null and  
            AP.FAILED_DTM is null;

  select max(PP.FAILED_DTM) into var_nsfDat

                              from ACCOUNTPAYMENT AP, PHYSICALPAYMENT PP  
                              where AP.ACCOUNT_NUM = var_accountNum(i) and   
                              AP.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT_STATUS = 3 and  
                              AP.PHYSICAL_PAYMENT_SEQ = PP.PHYSICAL_PAYMENT_SEQ and  
                              AP.CUSTOMER_REF = PP.CUSTOMER_REF and  
                              PP.PHYSICAL_PAYMENT_STATUS = 3 and  
                              PP.FAILURE_CODE_ID in (select PFC.FAILURE_CODE  
                                                     from CGPAYMENTFAILURECONFIG PFC  
                                                     where PFC.FAILURE_TYPE = 'Decline NSF')  ;

 <how to appned var_query1Rec with  var_writeOffdat and var_writeOffdat>                                 
 <how to make a PLSQl table of that record and return from function>



  end loop;
end loop;

end;
```

Comment: you can't do it because this variables have different types - one of them is record and other two - dates. You can add them in one collection but only if all of them have the same data type. As an option - you can add few OUT parameters and you them to return values from function

Comment: @Tatiana functions should only return one value. An function returning an object is the best way to go if they want to use this in an SQL statement

Comment: @kevinsky as far as I know, user-defind functions that are called from SQL statement must return valid SQL data types, not PL/SQL-specific types. So return an object will anyway prevent using this function in SQL

Answer (score 1):

If this function is not part of a package - why wouldn't it be? then you have no other choice but to declare a SQL Object type like this example:

```
CREATE TYPE person_typ AS OBJECT (
  idno           NUMBER,
 first_name     VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Declare the variables at the top of your function to access the type created.

```
type t_arr is table of person_typ ;
l_arr  t_arr := t_arr();
```

Then assign them in your code:

```
l_arr.extend;
l_arr(i).idno := xxx;
l_arr(i).first_name := yyyy;
```

The create function returns the object:

```
create or replace function test(p_actBillDat date) return person_typ as
.....
    return(l_arr);
end;
```

> But I would have this function in a package then in the package body header or spec you could do this:

```
type t_rec is
 record(x number
       ,y varchar2(100)
       );
 type t_tbl is table of t_rec index by binary_integer;
```

Then declare in your function:

```
 l_tbl t_tbl;
```

Then assign them in the function:

```
l_tbl(i).x := xxx;
l_tbl(i).y := yyy;
```

And finally just return the type in your function like this:

```
create or replace function test(p_actBillDat date) return t_tbl as
......
   l_tbl t_tbl;
begin
    .......
     for i in 1..counter loop
         .. SQL statements
         l_tbl(i).x := xxx;
         l_tbl(i).y := yyy;
     end loop;
     return l_tbl;
end;
```

Comment: Can it be done without touching schema? I don't want to define SQL type.

Comment: Yes it can be done easily as I've explained. Put the function into a package - look up how to create a package and package body then define the type in the package body as I've shown in the second example.